# File Transfer with smack android xmpp

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I am trying to implement file transfer from android app to spark (as testing) using the below code (from various blogs..)

```
 File f = new File(fullPAth);
     FileTransferManager manager123 =FileTransferManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
     final OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = manager123.createOutgoingFileTransfer("123456789@162.158.0.45/Test");
                try {
                    transfer.sendFile(f, "test_file");
                } catch (SmackException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

But always getting 503 Service unavailable error. Please help

Comment: Make sure that the service is available on your server

Comment: I can able to send and receive the text messages but only file transfer is not working. What service should I check?